# Problem of formatting bibliography with one beamerposter theme

Tags: beamer, biblatex, beamerposter

I am using the beamerposter theme `beamerthemeZH.sty` now to generate my poster. The theme is downloaded from the project [latex-beamerposter](https://github.com/deselaers/latex-beamerposter) on GitHub. The theme `beamerthemeZH.sty` is in the direction [`example/03/`](https://github.com/deselaers/latex-beamerposter/tree/master/examples/03). I am wondering whether anybody knows this beamerposter theme or has used this before.
My problem is, when I use `bibtex` to format the bibliography, information of bib items is too much for me and I did not find a suitable bst style. Then I am trying to use `biblatex` to format bibliography. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{ZH}}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german, english]{babel} % required for rendering German special characters
\usepackage{siunitx} %pretty measurement unit rendering
\usepackage{hyperref} %enable hyperlink for urls
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize,justification=justified]{caption}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered tabularx columns
\sisetup{per=frac,fraction=sfrac}
%%%Lines form here and before \title is added by myself%%%
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none,hyperref=true,style=nature,isbn=false,doi=false,eprint=false,url=false,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Bringa2012_NL.12.3351,
  author    = {Bringa, E. M. and Monk, J. D. and Caro, A. and Misra, A. and Zepeda-Ruiz, L. and Duchaineau, M. and Abraham, F. and Nastasi, M. and Picraux, S. T. and Wang, Y. Q. and Farkas, D.},
  title     = {Are Nanoporous Materials Radiation Resistant?},
  journal   = {Nano Letters},
  year      = {2012},
  volume    = {12},
  number    = {7},
  pages     = {3351-3355},
  note      = {PMID: 21651306},
  doi       = {10.1021/nl201383u},
  eprint    = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/nl201383u},
  file      = {:Are Nanoporous Materials Radiation Resistant_Nano Lett., 2012 12 (7) pp 3351–3355.pdf:PDF},
  groups    = {Nanowire irradiation, simulation},
  owner     = {Wenqiang},
  timestamp = {2014.09.22},
  url       = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/nl201383u},
}
@Article{Plimpton1995_JoCP.117.1,
  author    = {Steve Plimpton},
  title     = {Fast Parallel Algorithms for Short-Range Molecular Dynamics},
  journal   = {Journal of Computational Physics},
  year      = {1995},
  volume    = {117},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {1 - 19},
  doi       = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jcph.1995.1039},
  issn      = {0021-9991},
  owner     = {Wenqiang},
  review    = {LAMMPS original paper},
  timestamp = {2016.07.14},
  url       = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002199918571039X},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\title{\huge Test}
\author{Test}
\institute[]{\LaTeX}
\date{\today}
% edit this depending on how tall your header is. We should make this scaling automatic :-/
\newlength{\columnheight}
\setlength{\columnheight}{104cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.43\textwidth}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[center]{postercolumn}
            \begin{minipage}{.98\textwidth}  % tweaks the width, makes a new \textwidth
                \parbox[t][\columnheight]{\textwidth}{ % must be some better way to set the the height, width and textwidth simultaneously
                    \begin{myblock}{}
                      cite here\cite{Bringa2012_NL.12.3351}\cite{Plimpton1995_JoCP.117.1}
                    \end{myblock}\vfill
        }\end{minipage}\end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.57\textwidth}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[center]{postercolumn}
            \begin{minipage}{.98\textwidth} % tweaks the width, makes a new \textwidth
                \parbox[t][\columnheight]{\textwidth}{ % must be some better way to set the the height, width and textwidth simultaneously
                    \begin{myblock}{References}
                        \footnotesize
                        \printbibliography
                \end{myblock}\vfill
        }\end{minipage}\end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, only the first bib item show the sequence number `1`, the following ones do not have a number before the bib item.[image: the pdf file]
Could you please tell me how can I fix this problem? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of your problem. It is enough to post the code of a short beamer document with two bib entries so that we can see what is going on. Can you reproduce the problem with another (maybe a standard) theme?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I added my MWE, it seems very long though. The `sty` files are very long too, so I did not copy them here. The link is given in my question. If there are needed, please tell me. I also tried to use `biblatex` in standard `beamerposter` theme, it goes well. So, I think maybe there are some conflicts between `biblatex` and theme `beamerthemeZH.sty`, however, due to limited knowledge, I can not find them and I am trying to get help from experts.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the `\justify`, which the `ZH` beamertheme adds to the definition of the `block` environment. If this is removed the bibliography is numbered:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{ZH}

\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{
    \setlength{\mylength}{\textwidth+2ex}%
    \vskip2ex
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.8ex,dp=2ex, wd=\mylength, center,rounded=false,shadow=false,leftskip=1cm,colsep*=0ex]{block title}%
        \usebeamerfont*{block title}\centering \insertblocktitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip-9pt%
    {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5ex}}%
    \usebeamerfont{block body}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=false,shadow=false,center,wd=\textwidth,]{block body}%
        \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}\vbox{}%
        \begin{minipage}{0.96\textwidth}\vbox{}%
%       \justify
        }

\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none,hyperref=true,style=nature,isbn=false,doi=false,eprint=false,url=false,]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Bringa2012_NL.12.3351,
  author    = {Bringa, E. M. and Monk, J. D. and Caro, A. and Misra, A. and Zepeda-Ruiz, L. and Duchaineau, M. and Abraham, F. and Nastasi, M. and Picraux, S. T. and Wang, Y. Q. and Farkas, D.},
  title     = {Are Nanoporous Materials Radiation Resistant?},
  journal   = {Nano Letters},
  year      = {2012},
  volume    = {12},
  number    = {7},
  pages     = {3351-3355},
  note      = {PMID: 21651306},
  doi       = {10.1021/nl201383u},
  eprint    = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/nl201383u},
  file      = {:Are Nanoporous Materials Radiation Resistant_Nano Lett., 2012 12 (7) pp 3351–3355.pdf:PDF},
  groups    = {Nanowire irradiation, simulation},
  owner     = {Wenqiang},
  timestamp = {2014.09.22},
  url       = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/nl201383u},
}
@Article{Plimpton1995_JoCP.117.1,
  author    = {Steve Plimpton},
  title     = {Fast Parallel Algorithms for Short-Range Molecular Dynamics},
  journal   = {Journal of Computational Physics},
  year      = {1995},
  volume    = {117},
  number    = {1},
  pages     = {1 - 19},
  doi       = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jcph.1995.1039},
  issn      = {0021-9991},
  owner     = {Wenqiang},
  review    = {LAMMPS original paper},
  timestamp = {2016.07.14},
  url       = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002199918571039X},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\title{\huge Test}
\author{Test}
\institute[]{\LaTeX}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\cite{Bringa2012_NL.12.3351}\cite{Plimpton1995_JoCP.117.1}

\begin{block}{References}
    \printbibliography
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]